# What is the minimum number of stages $s$ required for a Runge-Kutta type numerical method of given order $p$?

Tags: numerical-methods, runge-kutta-methods

[These slides](https://www.cc.gatech.edu/classes/AY2015/cs4496_spring/slides/DiffEqu.pdf) (slide 42) give a table (same as Table 1.6 given in Butcher's [General Linear Methdos](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/acta-numerica/article/div-classtitlegeneral-linear-methodsdiv/68B6D07A0CBC9AC5DE06ED4048A22A3F) of the minimum number of stages $s$ for a Runge-Kutta type numerical method of order $p$ (the slides use $q$, but all the other references I'm working with use $q$ to refer to stage order and $s$ to refer to the number of stages, so I'm sticking with that convention). *Neither table specifies that this only applies to explicit methods.*

The table is reproduced below:

```
p   s
-----
1   1
2   2
3   3
4   4
5   6
6   7
7   9
8   11
9   12-17 (lecture notes only)
10  13-17 (lecture notes only)
```

For a numerical method (implicit or explicit) of order $p=2$, the minimum number of stages is $s=2$, but the Implicit Midpoint/Gauss-Legendre 2 method is has $p=2$, $s=1$. The same applies to Gauss-Legendre 4 ($p=4$, $s=2$), and so on (Gauss-Legendre methods have $p=2s$).

The slides state "The minimum number of stages necessary for an explicit method to attain order $p$ is still an open problem." This suggests that for implicit methods, it is not an open problem.

In Butcher's General Linear Methods, we also have the following.

> According to Table 1.6, it is suggested that, for p ≥ 5, it is necessary that s > p. We will now prove this result.
>
> **Theorem 1.7.** There does not exist an explicit Runge–Kutta method with order $p = s \ge 5$.

This along with the existence of [Gauss-Legendre and other implicit Runge-Kutta methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#Implicit_methods) with fewer stages than what's listed in this table, suggests that higher order implicit methods require fewer stages than explicit methods.

**So what's up with this table?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table definitely refers to explicit Runge-Kutta methods. It is indeed true that (implicit) Gauss-Legendre collocation methods satisfy $p = 2s$, and, to my knowledge, that's the highest order you can get with a fixed number of stages.

A recipe to achieve a certain order $p$ with explicit methods employing the minimum number of stages (i.e., function evaluations) is indeed unknown yet. It is a relevant question as explicit methods are way cheaper than the implicit ones, as no solution of nonlinear equation is required.